# Open tabs in gnome-terminal from python script

Tags: python

I'd like to open different gnome-terminal tabs and connect via ssh to different servers. To do this, I used to use a little bash script.

```
#!/bin/sh

hosts=("172.16.1.183" "172.16.1.184")
pass=Password123!

for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
  gnome-terminal --tab -- sshpass -p $pass ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$host
done
```

I'm forcing myself to start scripting in python, as I would like to learn it. That's why now I'm trying to do this with this python script instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

for servidor in ['172.16.1.183', '172.16.1.184']:
  subprocess.run(['gnome-terminal', '--tab', '--', 'sshpass', '-p', 'Password123!', 'ssh', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', 'root@',servidor])
```

It seems that for a second the tabs do open but then they close. As I don't know how to see any kind of log, it is hard for me to understand what's happening.

Could you please help me to understand what's happening? Is there any way to run these scripts with a "verbose" option like in bash with "-x" or things like -v, -vv, -vvv for instance?

Thank you very much!

edit: I'm using PYTHONVERBOSE=1 but I can't understand that output :/ is not like I can see an "error" anywhwere or even follow the step-by-step execution to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the username and hostname as two list elements. Instead it should be just one element. Change `'root@',servidor` to `'root@'+servidor`

Your code can be written in a better way as follows

```
cmd = 'gnome-terminal --tab -- sshpass -p sshpass ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@{}'
for servidor in ['172.16.1.183', '172.16.1.184']:
    subprocess.run(cmd.format(servidor).split())
```

Comment: Worked like a charm at the first try! :) I spent no less than one hour reading and trying things.

I tried to understand what the "split" was good for in here. Printing it I can see the difference, but I don't get why is necessary. Could you please explain this?

withouth split
172.16.1.183
with split
['172.16.1.183']

Comment: I would upvote you but I got this message saying I can't as per lack of reputation :/ sorry!